# How can I run gif animation on load then re-run on click

Tags: html

I've created a very short gif animation (4 frames) which I'd like to automatically run on page load.   It's set for 3 repeats only.
I've used the following code on a test html page which works on clicking the image.

```
    <img src="red-anim.gif" alt="" class="post-thumb" onclick='this.src=this.src'/>
```

However, I'd like it to run automatically on page load but still be available to run again when clicked.

I can't quite see how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
 <img src="red-anim.gif" alt="" class="post-thumb" id="myImg" onclick='this.src=this.src'/>
<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "red-anim.gif";
}
</script>
</body>
```